# Android: "no xtra servers were specified in the gps configuration"

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I wish to use the Google Map API in my android application. However, when I run it and display the activity that is to run the map, the application crashes.

The logcat says "no xtra servers were specified in the gps configuration".
My API key is correct, and my code seems to be fine.
Some weird thing, sometimes the application doesn't crash and the map actually works.

Do you know what that "xtra servers" error means?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPS xtra servers is Qualcomms' GPS assistance data, allowing you to speed-up initial GPS fixes. The xtra servers could be configured like this:

```
XTRA_SERVER_1=http://xtra1.gpsonextra.net/xtra.bin
XTRA_SERVER_2=http://xtra2.gpsonextra.net/xtra.bin
XTRA_SERVER_3=http://xtra3.gpsonextra.net/xtra.bin
```

Comment: These lines go in `/system/etc/gps.conf`. Note that you will either need to make a custom build or root your phone to change them.